# MS Excel : multiple lists into one

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm sure it's easier then I think.

I have  multiple vertical lists.
For example:

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

Item 4

Item 1.1

Item 2.1

Item 3.1

Item 4.1

Item 1.2

Item 2.2

Item 3.2

Item 4.2

I want to put these items into a horizontal list like below

| Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1.1 | Item 2.1 | Item 3.1 | Item 4.1 |
| Item 1.2 | Item 2.2 | Item 3.2 | Item 4.2 |

Comment: This is unfortunately not easy to do in Excel. It will either be a manual move job or write a VBA macro. The downside of a VBA macro is that it will likely take more time to write it than to manually move it, unless it is a recurring job or it are more than 100 rows/items. It might be easier to see if the list can be modified at the source (from where you got it, to follow this structure)

Comment: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4 is title Row?

Answer (score 1):

If your list is in column **A**, then try entering the formula in **B1**

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Item "&(COLUMN()-1)&IF(ROW()=1;"";"."&(ROW()- 1));$A:$A;1;0);"")`

and stretch this to the right and down until you see empty cells.
[image: Result]

Comment: Nice & easy solution,, you get +10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

Let's assign a "new row number" to each item. If we know we have four items in each list, then:

```
=QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,4)+1
```

[image]

We can filter the original data using the new row number, like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($A$1:$A$12,$B$1:$B$12=ROW()))
```

On row 1, ROW()=1. This FILTER then returns the first four values from column A. We then use TRANSPOSE to pivot them horizontally. By dragging the formula down to rows 2 and 3, we get the rest of the data:

[image]

If you prefer, you can forgo the first step, and just use this instead:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($A$1:$A$12,QUOTIENT(ROW($A$1:$A$12)-1,4)+1=ROW()))
```

[image]

Comment: Extension: consider each row to contain `Item a.b`, pick out a and b, then place that item in the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that your data is regular (ordered) and complete, with no skipped items. You basically have a Tx1 array to wrap into a n x m table where n x m = T.

We will use the position in our table (ROW,COLUMN) as an index into the array. Lets assume the array is in sheet1 column A and the new table is in sheet2. Then A1 in sheet2 is:

```
=INDEX(SHEET1!$A:$A, COLUMN()+(ROW()-1)*m)
```

Where m must be replace with the number of columns to wrap (4 in your example).